# iPhone Implement Search against API XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to implement a search feature in an iPhone app.
Basically, the user can enter some terms say "searchterm" and pass it as a URL to the API I am using. The API returns an XML. I need to parse the search results from what the user selects.

I just wanted to understand how this search thing will work. Any reference examples would be really helpful.
This will be somewhat similar to a search on iPhone App Store.

Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me your XML response return in which formate if its come in node then use Xpath Query else if you get attribute in your response then use simple Parsing delegate , i can send you simple delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the information that I need gets returned both in attributes as well as nodes in the XML.